# Curated Social Media Feeds on Hate, Corruption, Violence, and other negative society aspects?

Tags: social-media

I am looking to see a broad swath of negative/undesirable/polarizing content, so I can get a deeper sense of how big and pervasive these problems are (and to share that info with others). I am not looking for extremely perverse or violent things like violent videos with gore or anything, I am very sensitive to that stuff yet would like to still be exposed to it to some degree. Seeing examples such as [this recent Nevada people/police encounter](https://twitter.com/MichelleLhooq/status/1695952716915450301) really shapes your perspective.

I also just found [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1YmZeSxpz52qT-10tkCjWOwOGkQqle7Wd1P7ZM1wMW0E/htmlview?pru=AAABcql6DI8*mIHYeMnoj9XWUp3Svb_KZA) collecting "police brutality" tweets and videos. That is the exact type of thing I would like to find, but for other topics as well (including but not limited to political lying, climate-denial and other science denial, propaganda and misinformation campaigns, violence and brutality, racism and other forms of hate and discrimination, etc.). Putting it together to see how widespread and deep this stuff runs will be useful in communicating with others about possible ways to improve different aspects of society.

What are the go-to Twitter feeds or Facebook feeds (or TikTok/YouTube/etc., though I don't know much about those platforms) for this kind of negative content? I am not looking for videos of random people getting into fights and stuff like that, but socially negative/objectionable behaviors basically. Do you know of any good already-curated collections of stuff? If so, please share. If not, where could I find as much as possible relatively quickly, what are your suggestions?

When I search for "videos of racism" or "videos of people discriminating against others", mostly what I seem to be finding is videos of people explaining or teaching *why that is bad*, not the actual videos of evidence of these types of acts. I would like to find the examples to point to instead mainly, for the moment at least.

P.S. If you know of a more appropriate place to post this, like an appropriate Reddit thread, please let me know so I can fix that if necessary. I tried to post on Reddit but these were the wrong places:

- /r/AskReddit: Only allows 1-2 sentences in a post.
- /r/Politics: Only allows posting links.
- /r/SocialMedia: Is for marketers of social media I guess.

I couldn't find a place. There are Reddit "topics" in these areas, but you can't post in the topics it looks like, such as:

- [/t/social_issue](https://www.reddit.com/t/social_issue/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems an almost unanswerably broad question. Nor am I clear what you want to do with this or how you want to analyze it. Just to de/sensitize yourself? Research? Any answers I would give would be audience dependent.

As example, many states make some aggregate version of their Violent Death Reporting System (VDRS) public. If you have valid research questions you can ask for detailed line list data, which includes traumatic but well abstracted, not lurid narratives. I work with this data daily. Or overdose data. Or police violence data (mapping police violence, the counted, fatal encounters are three data collection projects). Unclear what you want.